# Helm override list in values.yml so that original list is NOT propagated

Tags: yaml, prometheus, kubernetes-helm

Let's says I have a default values.yml in a Helm chart that looks like:

```
orders:
  - order1
  - order2
  - order3
```

Now, I want to override THE ENTIRE LIST, using the usual `-f my-values.yaml` syntax, and it contains something like

```
orders:
 - order66
```

My problem is that in this way, the `order66` item gets MERGED in the list, so the list now has:

```
orders:
  - order1
  - order2
  - order3
  - order66
```

...while I want instead to OVERWRITE the entire list with my custom values.

An example of a real use-case is `scrape_configs` in [Prometheus values.yml](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/main/charts/prometheus/values.yaml).

What is the syntax to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's just one simple variable, you should be able to just run:

```
# helm install my_chart ./mychart -f values.yaml --set my_option=my_value
```

as explained [HERE](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/) (search for `--set` in that document).

However if it's a longer set of values, things get more complicated.
You can try to use `--set-file $file` option and move your values in there.

As shown [HERE](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#the-format-and-limitations-of-set) search for `--set-file key=`, so in your case you'll have:

```
# cat my_values_file
- order1
- order2
- order3
- order66

# helm install my_chart ./mychart -f values.yaml --set-file orders=my_values_file
```

You can also try running a different approach in "cleaning" the variable and settings it afterward:

```
# helm install my_chart ./mychart --set orders=null -f values.yaml
```

So that it's going to be emptied and then set with the content of what's in `values.yaml`

Be sure to run:

```
# helm install my_chart ./mychart --dry-run --debug --set orders=null -f values.yaml
```

to verify what the command will do before actually applying it.

Also, be aware that the order matter, as the right-most operator takes precedence.

Cheers